# Replace characters with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Using `preg_match()` I would like to match the following occurence in a string:

```
token=[and here 32 characters a-z0-9]
```

For example:

```
token=e940b20a98d01d08d21a919ecd025d90
```

I have tried

```
/^(token\=)[a-z0-9]{32}$/
```

but it did not work!

What I am trying to do is:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referer = preg_replace("/^(token=)[a-z0-9]{32}$/","token=".token(),$referer);
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the url doesn't certainly begin with `token` and ends with its value. You've probably confused `^` and `$` with word boundaries (`\b`). Also, there's no need for the capture group and no need to escape `=`.

```
/\btoken=[a-z0-9]{32}\b/
```

Comment: Additionally, no need to escape `=` nor to have the literal `token` in a captured group. Did you mean `/\btoken=([a-z0-9]{32})\b/` ?

Comment: @Jan True, I just didn't modify that in the OP's regex.

Comment: @Jan There's no need to capture-group the value of token, is there?

Comment: Well, I guess it's easier to capture it: https://regex101.com/r/aT0gH7/1

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't parse the referer using regexes when PHP already has built-in functions for this purpose: `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`.

Unfortunately there is no built-in function to build an URL from the component parts so users have to invent their own (see definition of the `Url` class at the end).

---

Changing the `token` query parameter:

```
// parse the referer
$components = Url::parse($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

// replace the token
$components['query']['token'] = token();

// rebuild the referer
$referer = Url::build($components);
```

Here's a simplified definition of my `Url` class:

```
/**
 * Url parsing and generating utility
 * 
 * @license https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT License
 * @author ShiraNai7               
 */   
final class Url
{
    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @return array
     */              
    static function parse($url)
    {
        $components = parse_url($url);
        if (false === $components) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid URL');
        }

        if (isset($components['query'])) {
            parse_str($components['query'], $components['query']);
        }

        return $components + array(
            'scheme' => null,
            'host' => null,
            'port' => null,
            'user' => null,
            'pass' => null,
            'path' => null,
            'query' => array(),
            'fragment' => null,
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $components
     * @param bool  $absolute     
     * @return string     
     */         
    static function build(array $components, $absolute = true)
    {
        $output = '';

        if ($absolute) {
            if (empty($components['host']) || empty($components['scheme'])) {
                throw new \LogicException('Cannot generate absolute URL without host and scheme being set');
            }

            if (!empty($components['scheme'])) {
                $output .= $components['scheme'] . '://';
            }

            if (!empty($components['user'])) {
                $output .= $components['user'];
            }
            if (!empty($components['pass'])) {
                $output .= ':' . $components['pass'];
            }
            if (!empty($components['user']) || !empty($components['pass'])) {
                $output .= '@';
            }

            $output .= $components['host'];

            if (!empty($components['port'])) {
                $output .= ':' . $components['port'];
            }
        }

        if (!empty($components['path'])) {
            $output .= (($components['path'][0] !== '/') ? '/' : '') . $components['path'];
        } else {
            $output .= '/';
        }

        if (!empty($components['query'])) {
            $output .= '?';
            $output .= http_build_query($components['query'], '', '&');
        }

        if (!empty($components['fragment'])) {
            $output .= '#' . $components['fragment'];
        }

        return $output;    
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to just get the token, but replace it with something different.